# Magento 1: Banner slider not showing?

Tags: magento-1.9, slider, banner-slider

I've added Responsive Owl Slider extension to Magento.
https://github.com/gogoleva/Vsourz_Bannerslider
But i don't know how to show slider on homepage.
Readme of this extension:
For you to integrate Responsive Owl Slider extension in your Magento website, please follow these 3 easy steps:

Install the extension from Magento Connect
Create Category, Upload Image Banners, Select Category and Select Effects you want
Insert the Code Snippet where the banners to be shown

I don't know how to insert the code snippet. Please help me

Comment: In the above extension,,,`app\code\community\Vsourz\Bannerslider\Block` Bannerslider.php `$this->getCategoryId();` returns null....Please use another extension

Comment: please check magento version i think block permission issue.

Comment: Thanks, Same issue but, today this solution is very helpfull. thanks again

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139892)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code CMS Home page

```
    {{block type="bannerslider/bannerslider" name="bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml"}}
```

It may be permission issue only.

You need to give permission from admin to your block bannerslider/bannerslider

> Go to Admin -> System -> Permission -> Blocks

- Add New Block and add block name bannerslider/bannerslider
- Set `isAllowed` to Yes
- Save Block and clear the cache

Comment: I added this code and slider had shown.
`{{block type="bannerslider/bannerslider" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" category_id="1" }}`
Thanks for reply my question !!!

Comment: please answer is working now please up vote.

Comment: Sorry. I can't up vote because i don't have enough reputation :(